# Paging using Linq-to-sql, Listview and Datapager

Tags: linq-to-sql, paging

I'm using LINQ to SQL to search a fairly large database and am using listview and datapager for paging. I am aware of the Skip() and Take() methods and have those working properly. However, I'm unable to use the count of the results for the datapager, as they will always be the page size as determined in the Take() method.

For example:

```
var result = (from c in db.Customers
              where c.FirstName == "JimBob"
              select c).Skip(0).Take(10);
```

This query will always return 10 or fewer results, even if there are 1000 JimBobs. As a result, the DataPager will always think there's a single page, and users aren't able to navigate across the entire result set.

How can I trick the datapager to display the pagecount for 1000, but bind 10 items at a time? I don't want to use objectdatasource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run a second query:

```
var count = Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == "JimBob").Count();
```

Comment: I get the count. But where do I use this count. How do I update the datapager that the count is 1000 and not 10.

Comment: Please help...It's been 2 days since I've been stuck with this. Am I missing something very simple?

Comment: I've never used the datapager... if it's supposed to do the paging for you, should you be limiting the query with skip & take? Or does it handle that as well?

Answer (score 0):

try using this..

```
    var result = (from c in db.Customers
          where c.FirstName == "JimBob"
          select c).Skip((PAGENUMBER-1 * 10)).Take(10);
```

check out the blogpost here on simple [LINQ Paging](http://wahabkotwal.blogspot.com/2011/06/aspnet-ajax-simple-paging-system-using.html)

Hope it helps.. :)